# How do I prevent accidental double clicks?

Tags: mouse

My Magic Mouse is going bad and sometimes detects a double click when I single click.

I know that there is a setting which allows you to set the upper threshold for double click speed, but not a lower threshold.

How do I set a lower threshold for double click speed?

Comment: Just replace the mouse. If the hardware is failing, no amount of software tweaking is going to be as reliable as correctly-functioning hardware.

Comment: I won’t replace such an expensive piece of hardware just because one of its many functions doesn’t work properly.

Answer (score 2):

At present, there is no way to do so.

However, one option to consider:

Do you tap, or do you click? I don't know if the Magic Mouse has these settings, but worth a shot:

If you tap, you might want to go over to clicking — for example, the trackpad has these options:

[image: Tap to click]

Alternatively, if you click, and would like to tap — simply enable that. If there's no such option, [this free app](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722) might help.

Comment: I don’t tap to click on my Magic Mouse because that results in too many accidental taps for me.

Comment: Sometimes I face the same problem.

Comment: But does tapping solve the accidental double-click problem?

Comment: @duci9y, did you end up solving this?

Comment: Tapping of course will solve the problem, but it just doesn't suit my hand. I couldn't find any solution for OS X.

Comment: @duci9y, sorry to hear. In any case, I assume this is the right answer then?

Comment: An answer cannot be accepted as the correct answer until the question is satisfactorily answered.

Comment: @duci9y, the answer to the question is that there is no solution to "set a lower threshold [than what's permitted by Mac OS X] for double click speed" — so how have I not "satisfactorily answered" your question?

Answer (score 0):

In Mountain Lion (and probably most if not all previous OSX versions) you can definitely set the threshold lower than the default click speed. If you have already set it the lowest setting, then I could only suggest replacing the mouse.

[image]

Comment: Um, sorry but you did not understand the question. That “Double-Click Speed” sets the upper threshold for double clicks. Lets assume “Slow” means 2 clicks per second and “Fast” means 20 clicks per second. If you move the slider all the way to the left, everything **faster** than 2 clicks per second will be detected as a double click. If you move it to the right, everything **faster** than 20 clicks per second will be detected as a double click. I want a setting such that everything **slower** than 20 clicks per second and everything faster than 2 clicks per second is detected as a double click

Comment: So neither of the two extremes: "Slow" vs. "Fast" work for you?