# How to avoid double clicking?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad, click

I find double clicking and right clicking difficult. MacOS allows me to `ctrl-click` so I never have to right click. Is there a way to never have to double click? Like `cmd-click`, a gesture or a System Preferences setting?

Answers that work for both my Magic Mouse and my track pad will be upvoted more enthusiastically :-)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUBGq.png You can increase the delay though..

Comment: @allan there are better questions/answers  :) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70034/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-double-clicks https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276357/applescript-how-to-double-click-right-click-at-cursor-location and so many to go through(which is a task for OP) ..

Comment: @ankii The question here is *how to **not** double click at all*. The two you linked, are *how to avoid **accidentally** double clicking* (not avoid altogether) and the other is *how to double click and right click simultaneously* (I can’t think of a use case for this, but hey).  Neither of those are “better” dupes than what I linked.

Comment: @allan https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/133232/double-click-in-applescript?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266784/how-do-i-make-the-mouse-click-at-current-location-using-applescript?rq=1 Alternatives are there.. One can bind AppleScript to a shortcut too. P.S. something is better than nothing :)

Comment: @ankii And both of those are about “automating” the double click, not *avoiding* it.  You’re looking for a dupe where it doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Allan  If OP can press a shortcut to run an AppleScript which clicks on the current mouse coordinates, it'd be very much helpful. Though their sentiments came out strong in "never have to double click" but I see it as "avoid double click as much as possible"